# Weight search in boolean mode with union mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to search across multiple tables, which is working however I want to weigh matches to the column "title" higher than matches to the column description.

```
SELECT 'about' AS a.about,title,null article ,null description

FROM about a 

WHERE 
(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

UNION
SELECT 'articles' AS null, b.title,b.article,b.description
from articles b 

WHERE
(
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
```

I have tried adding "AS relevance1" to the end of the match as below but it returns no results:

```
SELECT 'about' AS a.about,title,null article ,null description

FROM about a 

WHERE 
(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

UNION
SELECT 'articles' AS null, b.title,b.article,b.description
from articles b 

WHERE
(
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevence_1,
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevence_2
)

ORDER BY (relevance_1 * 3) + (relevance_2 * 2)  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of searching I found this approach works and is quite readable:

```
SELECT 'about' AS a.about,title,null article ,null description,MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as scale

FROM about a 

WHERE 
(
MATCH(a.about) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

UNION
SELECT 'articles' AS null, b.title,b.article,b.description,MATCH(b.title) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as scale
from articles b 

WHERE
(
MATCH(b.title,b.article,b.description) AGAINST ('\"$search\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)

ORDER BY scale  DESC
```